# Adobe illustrator- png -->svg converted images for Android

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to use vector asset for my android app to avoid resolution issues and to take other advantages. I have to convert all my png images to svg file and then I need to convert it into vector drawable resource. I tried to generate svg file with Adobe illustrator and tried to convert vector asset, unfortunately this is not working and given the following error.

Error message : The specified asset could not be parsed.please choose another asset.

I downloaded one svg file from google and it working fine.

My requirements are bellow.

1.Please suggest me any tool to convert png image to svg file (that needs to work for android vector asset)
2.Any open source tools to convert png to svg files.

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: PNG is pixels, saving/exporting to a different file format will not magically convert them. You will need to trace and/or redraw the image in Illustrator to be able to have the data as vectors.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad , please let me know if any tutorial to draw the image which will support for svg file ?

Comment: A quick search for _adobe illustrator tracing tutorials_ will reveal tons of them